# SQL Server summarize by week starting monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to summarize a revenue field by week, starting on Monday. My data looks as follows:

```
Date        Rev
+----------+--------
 4/10/2017     5
 4/11/2017     6
 4/12/2017     7
 4/13/2017     8
 4/17/2017     9
 4/19/2017     12
```

I would like the data to show the first day of the week and the summary of that week like:

```
Date        Rev
+----------+--------
 4/10/2017     26
 4/17/2017     21
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0, [date]) , 0) as [date], sum(rev)
from [data]
group by DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0, [date]) , 0)
order by [date]
```

> [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/962b7/6/0)

This maps to your sample data. It works because day 0 (1/1/1900) just happened to fall on a Monday. If you needed to use Sunday or Tuesday as your start of week you would adjust your input dates and offset accordingly.

Comment: Somehow this does not seem to work for all dates? `SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, '2023-01-01'), 0)` returns `2023-01-02` whereas the expected result is `2022-12-26`.

Answer (score 1):

An example is here, you can use datepart function to easily get the result:

```
create table #temp
([Date] datetime, Rev int)

insert into #temp values ('2010-01-01',10)
insert into #temp values ('2010-01-02',20)
insert into #temp values ('2010-01-07',60)
insert into #temp values ('2010-01-09',50)

SELECT DATEPART (wk, [Date]) AS Week, Sum(Rev) AS TotalRev
FROM #temp
Group By DATEPART (wk, [Date]);
```

Edit:
If you are insisting on using the first date value instead of week number, this is an alternative solution for you:

```
;with cte (firstdateofweek,weekno) as
(
   select min([Date]) as firstdateofweek ,DATEPART (wk, [Date]) weekno
   from #temp
   group by DATEPART (wk, [Date])
)
SELECT cte.firstdateofweek AS Week,sum(Rev) AS Sales
FROM #temp
INNER JOIN cte on DATEPART(wk, [Date]) = cte.weekno
Group By cte.firstdateofweek
```